# Connect external parachain node to local network relay chain

Tags: networking, private-network, rococo-local, live-network

I currently have a local relay chain with 4 validators and 2 collator nodes from 2 different parachains running. **I want to connect another node that is out of network** to one of the parachains. Is this possible? I'm pretty new to networking but it seems like it should be, given I set the right configuration for my ports.

I already have set the --ws-external and --rpc-external flags on my relay chain and parachain nodes. Would it be possible to connect and register the node form the other parachain if I just reference the public IP of the local machine? Or is it more complicated than this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call 'another node' as A.

If A holds the same genesis as relaychain, then it can join the network.

Actually, there are two nodes in the collator node. I mean:

```
A.relaychain.genesis == relaychain.genesis
```

Then you need to make sure:

- `--port xxx` is opening (IIUC, the default value for `A.relaychain.port` is `30334`)
- public IP, meet any one of the below requirements is enough

  - A connects to others

    - other nodes should have a public IP
  - others connect to A

    - If your router has a public IP then you could map it to your local machine

Once you see `(1 peers)` in A's log, which means it has joined the network.